# Can't use $regx when search by _id using Mongoose 6.6.3

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I want to search data by id and i try do like this

```
            _id: { $regex: '63a1bda46ec7f02cf5e91825', $options: 'i' },
        })
            .populate('user', 'name')
            .sort({ updatedAt: -1 });
```

but i got an  error  like this

> **Error: Can't use Options**

and then i delete the options and i got

> **Error: Can't use $regx**

Comment: What data type is the _id in that collection?

Comment: its ObjectId
default _id from mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#-regex):

> $regex
> Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries. MongoDB uses Perl compatible regular expressions (i.e. "PCRE" ) version 8.42 with UTF-8 support.

The regex you are using `'63a1bda46ec7f02cf5e91825'` is a 24-byte string, and ObjectID is stored as 12 binary bytes (see https://bsonspec.org/spec.html), so a regular expression will never match an ObjectID.

The 'Error: Can't use $regex' is coming from Mongoose, not mongod.  In your javascript you might be able to use the RegExp constructor like:
`new RegExp('^' + query + '.*')`

However that will still not permit matching an ObjectId with a regex.